# Why am I getting a "Value does not fall within the expected range" error when trying to set the credentials for an IIS Application Pool?

Tags: powershell, iis

I have an application pool called "test" that was previously created. I followed the instructions in this article here to have the pool running under an account:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/powershell/powershell-snap-in-making-simple-configuration-changes-to-web-sites-and-application-pools

Here is my code:

```
$pool = Get-Item IIS:\AppPools\test
$pool.ProcessModel.UserName = [string]'domain\testname'
$pool.ProcessModel.Password = [string]'testpassword'
$pool.processModel.identityType = 3
$pool | Set-Item
```

However, this gives me an error:

```
Set-Item : Value does not fall within the expected range.
At line:5 char:9
+ $pool | Set-Item
+         ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Item], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : path,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetItemCommand
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong? What value am I missing?

Comment: Try string value instead of numeric:  $pool.processModel.identityType = 'SpecificUser'

Comment: @GeorgeChakhidze Tried that, still nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. It appears that when cleaning up unused Nuget packages in my project, I've accidentally deleted Ninject, which is vital for dependency injection to work. I reinstalled several Ninject components that relates to ASP.NET and I was able to run it again.

When encountering this issue, it may be useful to go through the project and check if dependency injection is implemented or even partially implemented.